# Insecure dependency with Inline::Python

Tags: perl, taint

What could explain this compile-time error message when running [`Inline::Python`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Inline-Python/Python.pod) in [`-T`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Taint-mode) mode?

> Insecure dependency in open while running with -T switch at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/Inline/Python.pm line 193.

Line 193 is where `Inline::Python` opens `$o->{API}{location}`, which I take to be the "Inline DIRECTORY".

I have, of course, used the required options:

```
use constant _INLINE_DIR_ => '/var/myapp/inline';
use Inline Config => UNTAINT         => 1,
                     NO_UNTAINT_WARN => 1,
                     DIRECTORY       => _INLINE_DIR_;
```

I have made sure that `/var/myapp/inline` and everything inside it is writable by everyone, obviously including both root and the user that the application is `setuid`'ed to at run-time.

The very same script works without problem on my computer, whether I start it as root or not, running `Inline` 0.50 `Inline::Python` 0.43, but gives me this error when I try running it on a server that uses the same version of `Inline::Python` and either version 0.49 or 0.55 of `Inline`.

Comment: When you say /var/myapp/inline is writable by everyone, what are the actual permissions?  If it's world (or perhaps even just group) writable, Taint may be seeing that as an Insecure dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is different in different environments, my bet is that somehow there's an environment variable that either `Inline` or `Inline::Python` is reading before it does the step requested by the `UNTAINT` config parameter.

(Contrary to the comment, I don't think that file permissions could cause this message, only insecure dependencies on command-line parameters or environment variables)

Given that, I'd start your script by forcibly clearing the environment and then adding in only those environmental variables you know you need:

```
%ENV = ();
$ENV{'PATH'} = '/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin';  # Or whatever's appropriate
$ENV{'PYTHONPATH'} = '/usr/local/lib/python';   # Optional, if appropriate
# ... etc ...
```